# jstree checkbox plugin and node link conflict

Tags: jstree

I am implementing jsTree with grid and checkbox plugin. All is working fine, but if I set jsTree `a_attr.href`, then it is conflicting with `checkbox` events.

So when I click on node - it should follow the link, if I click on checkbox - it should be marked. What I am doing wrong?

I created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhskgky0/1/). But in this fiddle `href` attribute of link doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsTree will never follow the links, you have to redirect the user manually. To achieve that you need to decouple selection and checkboxes, so that checking a node does not select the node. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dhskgky0/3/

The key is the checkbox config:

```
checkbox: {
    //keep_selected_style:false,
    tie_selection : false,
    whole_node : false
},
```

Keep in mind you have to use a newer version (this demo uses 3.1.0) as the `tie_selection` option was not available in v.3.0.2 that you were using.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but when I added `activate_node` event, then on check it will follow link too. Please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Testertestx/dhskgky0/5/

Comment: I do not see an issue with firefox, maybe you are using another browser. But why do you want to use `activate_node.jstree`? It is a different event, `select_node.jstree` (as in the original demo) is the one you need, if you want to capture select events triggered by user interaction only check the event's `data.event` property.

Comment: After checking node and reloading, the `select_node.jstree` event is triggering without user interaction. It's why I am using `activate_node.jstree`

Comment: As I said in my previous post - keep using my original solution with `select_node.jstree`, just check for `if(data.event) { ` : http://jsfiddle.net/dhskgky0/6/

Comment: Thank you! I, somehow, missed that part. Now all is working fine!